# Where are setters/getters when using YAML/XML mapping for Doctrine in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml

In Symfony2, when [adding mapping information](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information) to tell Doctrine how to map my entity to the database, if I use [YAML](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html) or XML format instead of PHP annotations, how/where do I write getters/setters/other functions?

Answer (score 1):

> you can define mapping in `yml` or `xml` and still define entity class methods in the `.php`

---

## Symfony Docs

[Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information) show the metadata as annotations directly inside the Product class (option #1 PHP) at a different location `src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php` than alternative (option #2 YAML and #3 XML) `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Product.orm.*ml`.  This suggests that you can define the mapping in `*ml` and the getters/setters/other functions in the `php`.

Notice in the docs example the `AppBundle\Entity\Product` is specified in both files.  The class methods and mapping can be defined independently and related to each other as `AppBundle\Entity\Product`.

---

## Stackoverflow

Also note, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528108/yaml-or-annotation-mapping-in-doctrine-2) is misleading.  You DO have to write getters/setters even if you use YAML/XML, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528287/1438029) clarifies:

> Doctrine requires private/protected properties, so you'll still be
>   writing getters and setters. And you'll still be writing the mapping
>   info, just in another place.

Comment: Strictly speaking, D2 only needs private/protected to support lazy loading.  Public properties are fine as long as your queries load everything you need.